# POST a form to an API with React

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch-api, gatsby

I use Staticman ([staticman.net](https://staticman.net)) for comments on my Gatsby ([gatsbyjs.org](https://www.gatsbyjs.org)) site.

I've been using a classic HTML form with `method="POST"` and `action="https://api.staticman.net/..."`  parameter, as this is what Staticman expects ([docs](https://staticman.net/docs/index.html#step-3-hook-up-your-forms)).

However I'd like to make this more "React", and I've changed the form action to a `handleSumbit()` function:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  fetch("https://api.staticman.net/...", {
    method: "POST",
    body: event.target,
  })
}
```

I feel that this doesn't work because the API expects an [HTTP POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request), with an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type, whereas my `event.target` is a form with loads of React information.

How can I make my `fetch()` request look exactly like an HTTP POST form submission?

Comment: Staticman's maintainer recommends users to start his/her own API instance in https://github.com/eduardoboucas/staticman/issues/317#issuecomment-56525006.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I've found *a* solution. Here's my `handleSubmit` function:

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  // extract form data
  const formdata = new FormData(event.target)

  // convert FormData to json object
  // SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774073
  const json = {}
  formdata.forEach(function(value, prop){
    json[prop] = value
  })

  // convert json to urlencoded query string
  // SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562814 (comments)
  const formBody = Object.keys(json).map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(json[key])).join('&')

  // POST the request to Staticman's API endpoint
  const response = await fetch("https://dev.staticman.net/v3/entry/github/robinmetral/eaudepoisson/master/comments", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    body: formBody,
  })
    .then(response => {
      // reset form
      document.getElementById("comment-form").reset()
      // display success message
      document.getElementById("success").style.display = "block"
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      document.getElementById("failure").style.display = "block"
    })
}
```

This is what it does:

1. it extracts the submitted data as a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object
2. it converts the FormData to a JSON object, using a [snippet found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774073)
3. it converts the JSON to the expected `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type or "query string", using [another SO snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562814)
4. it sends the request to the API endpoint, catches errors and displays a success message

It's probably not the only solution, and if you see something that I could improve, please let me know in the comments or [send me a PR](https://github.com/robinmetral/eaudepoisson/blob/master/src/components/CommentForm.js)!

Answer (score 4):

I'd rebuild that POST data from your component state using something like the `query-string` package. Not sure on the specifics of staticman, but I presume you have form values in your react component's state so you could do something like:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  fetch("https://api.staticman.net/...", {
    method: "POST",
    body: queryString.stringify({
      this.state.username,
      this.state.subject
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on query strings! I ended up finding a way to convert FormData to a query string manually (via JSON). Not perfect, but it's working :)