# formData received object contains brackets on the key, can't parse them to Json

Tags: json, express, multipartform-data, form-data

I have a front-end application that sends a formData which contains arrays, so I'm using "object-to-formdata" to parse an the following object:

```
{
        "profileImage": {
            "name": "5574c060-853b-4999-ba39-1c66d5329704",
            "size": 364985,
            "mimetype": "image/png",
            "url": "uploads/5574c060-853b-4999-ba39-1c66d5329704"
        },
        "skills": [],
        "lessonsFinished": [],
        "classes": [],
        "_id": "5e3c2f8c80776b12cc336fdf",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$iZ3/BuklZ1FCGlyQDPUyMOhcWAfei5yl.llYScbWIv12XWcsokrgS",
        "username": "adrian",
        "verified": false,
        "status": "student",
        "color": "blue",
        "verificationCode": "50SZWPCHDL685C",
        "__v": 0,
        "lastName": "Test",
        "name": "Test",
    }
```

The object contains objects and arrays, and when parsed and sent to the backend, which uses express, with bodyParser and "express-fileupload" as a file manager, I receive this object:

```
{
    'profileImage[name]': '5574c060-853b-4999-ba39-1c66d5329704',   
    'profileImage[size]': '364985',
    'profileImage[mimetype]': 'image/png',
    'profileImage[url]': 'uploads/5574c060-853b-4999-ba39-1c66d5329704',
    'skills[]': '',
    'lessonsFinished[]': '',
    'classes[]': '',
    _id: '5e3c2f8c80776b12cc336fdf',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '$2b$10$iZ3/BuklZ1FCGlyQDPUyMOhcWAfei5yl.llYScbWIv12XWcsokrgS',
    username: 'adrian',
    verified: 'false',
    status: 'student',
    color: 'blue',
    verificationCode: '50SZWPCHDL685C',
    __v: '0',
    lastName: 'Test',
    name: 'Test',
  }
```

I cannot seem to find a way of parsing this into a normal Object, since I need to use the full object as a query parameter for mongoose.

My Express configuration goes as follows:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const express = require('express');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(fileUpload())
```

Finally, I have the endpoint in which I am receiving the formData:

```
exports.create = function (model) {
    return async function (req, res, next) {
        try {
            let document = req.body;
            if (req.files) {
                Object.keys(req.files).forEach(key => {
                    let file = req.files[key]
                    file.mv(upload_dir + file.name, (err) => {
                        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
                    });
                    document[key] = {
                        name: file.name,
                        size: file.size,
                        mimetype: file.mimetype,
                        url: upload_dir + file.name
                    }
                })
            }
            const newDocument = await new model(req.body).save();
            res.status(200).send(newDocument);
        } catch (err) {
            return next({
                status: 500,
                message: err.message
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the file just fine, and the rest of the data as well, but i cannot find a way of parsing the "encoded" (as in surrounded by brackets) object keys.
I tried building a recursive function to decode them but after several hours I couldn't find a solution and I figured there must be another way already working.

I tried the solutions presented in this thread: [How to convert FormData(HTML5 Object) to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431322/how-to-convert-formdatahtml5-object-to-json) but those just create an Object with the brackets included in the key...

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a best practive** to convert your `key[array]`, but for this time, maybe you can use this code below **to parse** the `key[array]` object to real object.

```js
const myArrays = {
    'profileImage[name]': '5574c060-853b-4999-ba39-1c66d5329704',   
    'profileImage[size]': '364985',
    'profileImage[mimetype]': 'image/png',
    'profileImage[url]': 'uploads/5574c060-853b-4999-ba39-1c66d5329704',
    'skills[]': '',
    'lessonsFinished[]': '',
    'classes[]': '',
    _id: '5e3c2f8c80776b12cc336fdf',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '$2b$10$iZ3/BuklZ1FCGlyQDPUyMOhcWAfei5yl.llYScbWIv12XWcsokrgS',
    username: 'adrian',
    verified: 'false',
    status: 'student',
    color: 'blue',
    verificationCode: '50SZWPCHDL685C',
    __v: '0',
    lastName: 'Test',
    name: 'Test',
  };

  function parseFormDataToObject(formObject) {
    Object.keys(formObject).forEach((key, index) => {
      let firstIndex = key.indexOf('[');
      let lastIndex = key.lastIndexOf(']');
      
      if(firstIndex !== -1 && lastIndex !== -1) {
        let name = key.slice(firstIndex + 1, lastIndex);
        let newKey = key.slice(0, firstIndex);
        if(!name) {
          formObject[newKey] = [];
        } else {
          if(!formObject[newKey]) {
            formObject[newKey] = {};
          }
  
          // console.log(myArrays[key]);
          formObject[newKey][name] = formObject[key];
        }
        delete formObject[key];
      }
    });

    return formObject;
  };

  console.log(parseFormDataToObject(myArrays))
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you! this solved the issue but unfortunately it only works for one-dimensional arrays or objects.

I found out that the culprit was express-fileupload, I should have configured it as app.use(fileUpload({ parseNested: true })) instead of without parameters

Answer (score 0):

Solved!, I found out that 'express-fileupload' overrides bodyParser, and it defaults to an option that flattens the output, to solve this, set fileupload as:

```
app.use(fileUpload({
     parseNested: true 
}));
```