# How to pass html form arrays to PHP with fetch()?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, fetch-api

I have a form which I get the data from with `new FormData(form)`. I'm having trouble getting my HTML arrays to properly pass over to PHP. I'm using vanilla JS and for example, in jQuery, using `serializeArray()` would have serialized my HTML into something PHP understands. But now with JSON.stringify, it seems to ignore HTML arrays completely and I get this:

`{"postData[0][val]":"1"}` passed over to PHP, where I would expect

`{"postData": ["0": ["val": "1"]]}`

My **HTML**:

```
<select name="postData[0][val]">
    <option value="1">nothing</option>
    <option value="2">boy</option>
    <option value="3">girl</option>
</select>

<input name="postData[0][val2]" type='number'>
```

My **Javascript**:

```
const formData = new FormData(form).entries();
let postData = {};

for (var pair of formData) {
    postData[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}

fetch(`${base}events/play/${event_id}`, {method: 'post', body: JSON.stringify(postData)})
```

I am properly reading the input in PHP.

Comment: `postData[0][val]` is a string and is the name of the `select` field. So `{"postData[0][val]":"1"}` is indeed what I would expect from your code.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as HTML arrays. HTML is just a markup language and doesn't know about data types

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431322/how-to-convert-formdatahtml5-object-to-json

Comment: I didn't know another way to express what I need to do here. Because indeed HTML understands them as a string, but `serializeArray()` from jQuery was able to pass it along so that PHP understood it as an array. I'm looking for similar (and hopefully standard) functionality here.

Comment: I think there might be something there that does, @twain. It looks like a solution to this may not come out of the box in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I had mistakenly believed that I had to `JSON.stringify()` all fetch POST requests to PHP; this was not the case. From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body):

> Both requests and responses may contain body data. A body is an instance of any of the following types: ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob/File, string, URLSearchParams, **FormData**

I was able to reduce it down to only these two lines:

```
const postData = new FormData(form);
fetch(`${base}events/play/${event_id}`, {method: 'post', body: postData})
```

Now it's sent in as $_POST, not `file://input`. Not my finest moment, but I did find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431322/how-to-convert-formdatahtml5-object-to-json) to be helpful for those who need help with something similar.