# Upload Document in Django Rest Framework Dynamic Form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

In my Djago-React Application I am creating a form which has dynamic fields as well as an option to upload the document

For that I am using `multipart/form-data` and its working fine when I am using it only to upload the document but as soon as I enter the data in dynamic fields the serializer stops handling the data.

Example data:

```
Form Data:
transaction_no: 2341
document: (binary)
items[0][product]: 5
items[0][quantity]: 1
items[0][fault]: Repairable
items[1][product]: 4
items[1][quantity]: 2
items[1][fault]: Return
allotment: 122
```

Response:

```
{"items":[{"product":["This field is required."]},{"product":["This field is required."]}]}
```

Serializer:

```
class DeliveredItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DeliveredItems
        fields = "__all__"


class DeliveredSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    items = DeliveredItemsSerializer(many=True,required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Delivered
        fields = "__all__"


    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_objects = validated_data.pop('items', None)
        prdcts = []
        try:
            for item in items_objects:
                i = DeliveredItems.objects.create(**item)
                prdcts.append(i)
            instance = Delivered.objects.create(**validated_data)
            print("prdcts", prdcts)
            instance.items.set(prdcts)
            return instance
        except:
            instance = Delivered.objects.create(**validated_data)
            return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        items_objects = validated_data.pop('items',None)
        prdcts = []
        try:
            for item in items_objects:
                print("item", item)
                fk_instance, created = DeliveredItems.objects.update_or_create(pk=item.get('id'), defaults=item)
                prdcts.append(fk_instance.pk)
            instance.items.set(prdcts)
            instance = super(DeliveredSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
            return instance
        except:
            instance = super(DeliveredSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
            return instance
```

Models:

```
class DeliveredItems(models.Model):

    choices = (('Repairable', 'Repairable'),('Return', 'Return'), ('Damage', 'Damage'), ('Swap Return', 'Swap Return'))
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fault = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Repairable", choices=choices)

class Delivered(models.Model):

    allotment = models.ForeignKey(Allotment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(DeliveredItems)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='delivered/', null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I handle the dynamic data that don't come in a list and comes as something like this `items[0][product]: 5`?

I need the data to be in this format:

```
{
  "transaction_no": 2335,
  "delivered": false,
  "document": {
    "uid": "rc-upload-1599739825759-7"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "product": 4,
      "quantity": "12",
      "fault": "Repairable"
    },
    {
      "product": 5,
      "quantity": "1",
      "fault": "Return"
    }
  ],
  "allotment": 116
}
```

Comment: what's your request data that you expected?

Comment: @CuongDaoVan I expected the data to be in JSON format

Comment: convert it to json: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431322/how-to-convert-formdatahtml5-object-to-json

Comment: @CuongDaoVan Is there a more backend oriented solution for this ?

Comment: you can fetch data as a form and handle form as dict in your viewset

Comment: @CuongDaoVan I have updated the question with required output, Can you please have a look?`

Comment: I have edited, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

please try this one if you want to handle form data in DRF
in view, please inherit `viewsets.ModelViewSet`

```
  def dict_shallow_copy(d):
   return dict(d.items())      
  def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if "data" in kwargs:
        data = kwargs.get("data", {})
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            data = dict_shallow_copy(data)
            //get your data here, sameple like this
            data['items'] = self.kwargs
            data['transaction_no'] = self.kwargs
            kwargs['data'] = data
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Invalid data type")
    return super().get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```