# Javascript generic way of retrieving values from all Input types, Selects, etc

Tags: javascript, performance

I am currently working on a piece of JavaScript that should generate a JSON object from as many types of inputs, selects, etc. by retrieving the name property as key and the value of the input as value.

I was wondering if there is a fancier way of achieving this than in the code snippet below.

```js
function generateJson() {
  var resultJsonString = {};

  var selects = document.getElementsByClassName("SelectClass");
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("InputClass");
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("CheckboxClass");


  for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    resultJsonString[selects[i].getAttribute("name")] =   selects[i].options[selects[i].selectedIndex].text;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    resultJsonString[inputs[i].getAttribute("name")] = inputs[i].value;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    resultJsonString[checkboxes[i].getAttribute("name")] = checkboxes[i].checked;
  }
  return JSON.stringify(resultJsonString);
}
```

As you can see I have to make dozens of lists and loop through them all since gathering the value doesn't work the same across different kinds of inputs and the like. I would like to reduce the number of lists and for loops I have to create.

If you need more details, I am happy to supply them.

Comment: See https://javascript.info/formdata , it will take form element and get all values at once.  and then convert to JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431322/how-to-convert-formdata-html5-object-to-json

Comment: Indeed, FormData already does that, I think you are reinventing the wheel

Comment: You could have a single loop over `form.elements`, but you'd still need to switch on the element type in that loop.

Comment: Thank you guys, formdata did the trick!