# How does one create, collect and programmatically (one entry per form-element) aggregate objects from related form-elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce, form-control

I want to group by data objects from the children of a parent `<div>`

This is my code:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <div id="parent-div">
    <div>
      <input type="text" style="margin: 0;" name="t-name-1" value="value1" />
      <span>
        <input type="text" name="t-quantity-1" value="1" />
        <input type="text" name="t-frequency-1" value="6" />
      </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" style="margin: 0;" name="t-name-2" value="value2" />
      <span>
        <input type="text" name="t-quantity-2" value="2" />
        <input type="text" name="t-frequency-2" value="8" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

```
var group = [];

$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    var elements = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
  
  for(var i = 0 ; i < elements.length - 1 ; i++){
        var item = elements.item(i);
        //console.log(i, item.name, '-', item.value);
        
        if(item.name.includes(item.name.split("-")[2])){
            var obj = {};
          var name = item.name.split("-")[1];
          obj[ name ] = item.value
                    group.push(obj);
        }
    }
    
    console.log(group);
});
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
[{
  name: "value1"
}, {
  quantity: "1"
}, {
  frequency: "6"
}, {
  name: "value2"
}, {
  quantity: "2"
}, {
  frequency: "8"
}]
```

The desired output:

```
var group = [
  {
    "name": "value1",
    "quantity": "1",
    "frequency": "6"
  },
  {
    "name": "value2",
    "quantity": "2",
    "frequency": "8"
  }
]
```

This is a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7yxzpsd5/45/

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/463ktpfq/27/ and this post for explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/59234388/536590

Comment: @MCM13 ... Regarding all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible approach does not make any assumptions about a form's inner DOM hierarchy. It instead would focus on the naming schema which all form-element's `name` attributes have in common, and which is ... `"t-<key>-<id>"`.

Thus an entirely DOM-structure agnostic but partially re-usable approach would be bipartite / two-folded.

- The first part does introduce the regex upon which any form-element will be identified. This regex is as follows ... `/^t-(?<key>\w+)-(?<id>\d+)$/`. It features [named groups for capturing](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) a `name` value's `key` and `id` part. The actual task ...

  - transforms the form elements collection [into an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#syntax)
  - [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)s all valid (according to the regex) form elements.
  - [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)s the filtered array into a list of `dataItems`
  - The reducer function gets provided the regex as part of a config object which is passed as [*initial value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) to `reduce` as well.
- The second task is implemented as generic and re-usable function which creates and stores `dataItem` objects upon a form element's extracted `id` as well as this element's extracted `key` and its `value`.

```js
function collectDataItemsByElementKeyAndId(collector, elmNode) {
  const { regX, list, map } = collector;
  const { key, id } = regX.exec(elmNode.name)?.groups ?? {};

  let dataItem = map[id];
  if (!dataItem) {

    dataItem = map[id] = {};
    list.push(dataItem);
  }
  Object.assign(dataItem, { [key]: elmNode.value });
  
  return collector;
}

function handleSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  const regXKeyAndId = /^t-(?<key>\w+)-(?<id>\d+)$/;

  const dataItemList = Array
    .from(this.elements) // `this` refers to the form element.

    .filter(elm => regXKeyAndId.test(elm.name))
    .reduce(collectDataItemsByElementKeyAndId, {

      regX: regXKeyAndId,
      map: {},
      list: [],

    }).list;

  console.log({ dataItemList });
}

$('#myForm').on('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <div id="parent-div">
    <div>
      <input type="text" style="margin: 0;" name="t-name-1" value="value1" />
      <span>
        <input type="text" name="t-quantity-1" value="1" />
        <input type="text" name="t-frequency-1" value="6" />
      </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" style="margin: 0;" name="t-name-2" value="value2" />
      <span>
        <input type="text" name="t-quantity-2" value="2" />
        <input type="text" name="t-frequency-2" value="8" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#myForm > #parent-div > div')
  var group = []

  divs.forEach(div => {
    var inputs = div.querySelectorAll('input')
    var obj = {}

    inputs.forEach(i => {
      var name = i.getAttribute('name').split('-')[1]
      obj[name] = i.value
    })

    group.push(obj)
  })

  console.log(group)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div id="parent-div">
    <div>
      <input type="text" style="margin: 0;" name="t-name-1" value="value1" />
      <span>
        <input type="text" name="t-quantity-1" value="1" />
        <input type="text" name="t-frequency-1" value="6" />
      </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" style="margin: 0;" name="t-name-2" value="value2" />
      <span>
        <input type="text" name="t-quantity-2" value="2" />
        <input type="text" name="t-frequency-2" value="8" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```