# Unable to send data over Websocket using FormData( ) because it cannot be stringified

Tags: reactjs, image, file-upload, websocket, form-data

**Frontend: React.js

Backend : Django Rest Framework Python**
I'm trying to send data as FormData over a WebSocket using the client.send() method.
The data over the WebSocket is transmitted as a string but FormData cannot be converted into a string as it is a special type of Object

```
  addMessage = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("room_id", this.state.currentRoomId);
    formData.append("messageBody", this.state.curMessage);
    formData.append("sender", this.props.user.name);
    formData.append("message_Type", "text");

    console.log("message being sent = ", formData);
    try {
      this.client.send(JSON.stringify({ message: formData }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error); // catch error
    }
  };
```

When I try to stringify the formData it returns an empty Object "{}".

If I send this as an object it works, as the object is stringified and parsed to JSON at the backend ( in python ).But using JSON.stringify() on formData returns {}

I've tried sending it without stringifying, and it gets sent as a string "[Object FormData]"

**Sent**

```
      this.client.send(formData);
```

**Received**

[image]

When I stringify it and send it, the rest of the object is stringified but the formData gets sent as { } (as mentioned above that it returns an empty object on JSON.stringify() )

**Sent**

```
      this.client.send(JSON.stringify({ message: formData }));
```

**Received**

[image]

**Sending As an Object**

When sending it as an object using

**Sent**

```
    const message = {
      room_id: this.state.currentRoomId,
      sender: this.props.user.name,
      messageBody: this.state.curMessage,
      message_Type : "text"
    }
    try {
      this.client.send(JSON.stringify({ message: message }));
    }
    ........
```

**Received**

[image]

it is getting sent perfectly

**Reason for using FormData and Not a Simple Object:**
Previously, I was just sending text messages but now I'm also uploading an image so for that I need to append the image in formData Object and send over the web server

```
      formData.append("image", this.state.selectedFiles);
```

**Any Idea to how to solve this? Either send the formData object intact over the websocket that only sends data as strings or suggest some way to send the image as a part of Object!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert FormData (HTML5 object) to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431322/how-to-convert-formdata-html5-object-to-json)

Comment: Why do you even bother with `FormData` instead of using a simple object?

Comment: @Konrad as I mentioned the reason for using formData was uploading an image, and the data over Websocket can be sent as a string. 
So even though we can copy the formData but when we stringify it and send it. the "file" loses its "File/Image" properties upon parsing it back to JSON at the backend and cannot be treated as a file i.e. Uploaded etc.

That's why it has to be a FormData Object

Anyways, I implemented the feature by using a bit different approach that used both the FormData and the JSON Object so thanks